# While inside While results

Tags: php

I'm trying to get data from While inside While.
In first while i get documents and in second i'm trying to get addicional values related with document;

I get data but result of second while it's duplicated like this:

```
INDEX A - Value A

INDEX B - Value A

INDEX C - Value A

INDEX D - Value A

INDEX A - Value B

INDEX B - Value B

INDEX C - Value B

INDEX D - Value B

INDEX A - Value C

INDEX B - Value C

INDEX C - Value C

INDEX D - Value C

INDEX A - Value D

INDEX B - Value D

INDEX C - Value D

INDEX D - Value D
```

**Expected results I'm trying to have is:**

```
INDEX A - Value A

INDEX B - Value B

INDEX C - Value C

INDEX D - Value D
```

Here is my code:

```
$query = "
    SELECT *
    FROM documents
    WHERE document_folder_id=$folder_id";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$num = mysql_numrows($result);

<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" id="example">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Document</th>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Classification</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            <?php
                $i=0;
                while ($i < $num) {
                $document_id = mysql_result($result,$i,"document_id");
                $document_number = mysql_result($result,$i,"document_number");

                $document_classification_id = mysql_result($result,$i,"document_classification_id");
                $document_classification_description = mysql_result($result,$i,"document_classification_description");
                            ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $document_number;  ?></td>

                <td><?php echo $document_date; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $document_classification_description; ?>

                    <?php
                    // get indexes
                    $query2 = "SELECT * FROM documents_indexes_values
                                LEFT JOIN document_indexes ON value_index_id = value_id 
                                WHERE value_document_id = $document_id"; 
                    $result2 = mysql_query($query2) or die(mysql_error());

                    while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2)){
                        echo "<br />";
                        echo $row2['index_description']. " - ". $row2['value_text'];
                        echo "<br />";
                    }
                    ?>
                </td>
                <? } ?>
            </tr>

            <?php
            $i++;
            }
            ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

I'm like to know a correct way to have while, where do I wrong?

Comment: What is the result of the query ($result2)?

Comment: The usual warning upfront [Dont use mysql_*](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php), see also [Choosing an API](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php)

Comment: Your code also outputs two more columns with document number and date. It would be useful to have this included in your question to see which lines belong to which outer loop iterations.

Comment: Addedd first part of code, @Stah, $result2 return Resource#65

Comment: I mean the actual data @HidDencum

Comment: @Stah return First part of post: INDEX A - Value A

INDEX B - Value A

INDEX C - Value A

INDEX D - Value A

INDEX A - Value B

INDEX B - Value B

INDEX C - Value B

INDEX D - Value B

INDEX A - Value C

INDEX B - Value C

INDEX C - Value C

INDEX D - Value C

INDEX A - Value D

INDEX B - Value D

INDEX C - Value D

INDEX D - Value D

Comment: How does the table definitions look like? It looks like you have the join condition wrong. The problem is not with the while inside while, but how your tables are defined and what the common `id` is in `documents_indexes_values` and `document_indexes`.

Comment: @ Olaf: you are right, I checked out again FK and now worked right.

Comment: @all: thanks for your time wasted to help me. I'm very grateful.